# Assuming drive cache

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub, uefi, elementary-os

I just made a bootable USB stick with elementary os using Rufus, and I'm trying to get my Acer Aspire V15 Nitro to dual boot with w10 and yeah, not working or else I wouldn't be posting here.

Anyway I got this error : `no caching mode page found [...]`

I've looked all over internet nothing helped me, and I really need this dual boot.

I'm in UEFI mode and I've disabled secure boot, I'm able to reach the grub install page where it lets me choose between install, try, check etc, but then it stops :(

[Images of the error](https://imgur.com/gallery/mjebs)

As asked in the comments, this edit will explain exactly what happens :

I shutdown ​Windows, go into the BIOS and deactivate the secure boot and change the boot order so it tries to boot into the USB stick so I can install Elementary OS on a free partition.

I reboot and press F12 to boot into grub, I try to install right away and I get this message, nothing changes, the LED on the stick doesn't flash. I reboot and try modifying the commands with things I've found on the internet but nothing there either. Most things I've seen on the internet are for people that have already installed a Linux distribution and they're asked to modify files in /etc which I can't do because I haven't booted in Linux yet. So yeah that's how far I've got, just the error with the cache and that's it.

Comment: Anyone please ? I really need it :(

Comment: Please [explain further](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/350968/edit) why none of the many results for _no caching mode page found_ were suitable for your needs. [Please also explain](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/350968/edit) exactly what does happen when you attempt to boot from your USB stick. At the moment we only have "it doesn't work", which doesn't give us much to go on.

Comment: That error would not prevent your machine from booting up. Read your logs again.

Comment: Done, I've modified my post and added pictures

Comment: That message ( which is not an error ) is perfectly normal for USB sticks and is harmless.